# Complementing Application.Resources.Style with UserControl.Style for DataRow in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have a *global* style used in all the applications `DataGrid`'s, defined in the `Application.Resources`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="StyleDataGridRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="DataGrid.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="DataGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGrid.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="DataGrid.IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="DataGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGrid.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Application:Resources>
```

In my `UserControl` I would like to add a style - keeping the global style - to highlight a row depending on an item used in this `DataGrid`. I could define this style in the `UserControl`'s resources:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>            
            <Style x:Key="priceMissing" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=priceIsMissing}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

The *global* style is applied to the `UserControl`'s `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCalculatedServices"
    Margin="20,0,0,0"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource StyleDataGridCell}"
    DataContext="{Binding}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding calculationServiceCodes.collection}"                              
    Style="{StaticResource StyleDataGrid}"
    RowStyle="{StaticResource StyleDataGridRow}">
```

Does anyone know a way to use the *global* style on a `DataGrid` and complement it with the *local* style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what the [`BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Style.BasedOn);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property is for.

> Styles can be based on other styles through this property. When you use this property, the new style will inherit the values of the original style that are not explicitly redefined in the new style.

Specify the `StyleDataGridRow` style as the base style for `priceMissing`.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <Style x:Key="priceMissing" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleDataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=priceIsMissing}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then use the `priceMissing` style in your `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCalculatedServices
    ...
    RowStyle="{StaticResource priceMissing}">
```

You could of course rename the `priceMissing` style to `StyleDataGridRow` instead. The style would then be overwritten in the scope of the `UserControl`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for teaching me the `BasedOn` property in such an excellent and simple way! This will make things much easier from now on.